# thymeleaf + i18n - how to concatenate value from controller and i18n?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a table field that's supposed to display an internationalized value for a persisted boolean value.

In my i18n file, I have the folloing entries:

```
gen.true=<value for true>
gen.false=<value for false>
```

On the table, I have:

```
<td style="text-align: center" th:text="#{gen.${pojo.<value>}}">
```

If I leave it as:

```
<td style="text-align: center" th:text="${pojo.<value>}">
```

I only get `true` or `false`, without internationalization.

Instead of the current displayed value of

```
??gen.pojo.recurrent??
```

I'd like it to show `<value for true>` or `<value for false>`.

How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td style="text-align: center" th:text="#{${'gen.' + pojo.recurrent}}">xxx</td>
```

or using preprocessing http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing

```
<td style="text-align: center" th:text="#{gen.__${pojo.recurrent}__}">xxx</td>
```